# Retrieving a boolean from another activity causes a NullPointerException (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

As I said in the title, I'm trying to retrieve a boolean from the intent.
Basically what I'm trying to do is going to activity2, there, I click a button and clicking that will make me jump into the main activity and send a boolean with the value "true" with the intent, and retrieve it in the main activity.

This is the code in the main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var a = intent.getBooleanExtra("a", false)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var btn: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity2::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    if(a) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```

}

This is the code in the second activity

```
class MainActivity2 : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

    var btn2: Button = findViewById(R.id.button2)

    btn2.setOnClickListener {
        var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity2, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("a", true)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

}

What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

You assign `a` immediately as soon as a new instance of the `MainActivity` is created. At that point it's possible that you boolean extra hasn't been set yet.

You can either make it lazy or retrieve it inside your `onCreate` function.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val a = intent.getBooleanExtra("a", false)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write below line inside **onCreate** method, in your current code you have written it outside of onCreate method.

```
var a = intent.getBooleanExtra("a", false)
```